# How do I fix this unicode/cPickle error in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, pickle

```
ids = cPickle.loads(gem.value)

loads() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

Comment: Why is `gem.value` unicode and not a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cPickle.loads` wants a byte string (which is exactly what `cPickle.dumps` outputs) and you're feeding it a unicode string instead.  You'll need to "encode" that Unicode string to get back the byte string that `dumps` had originally given you, but it's hard to guess what encoding you accidentally imposed on it -- maybe `latin-1` or `utf-8` (if `ascii` don't worry, either of those two will decode it just great), maybe `utf-16`...?  It's hard to guess without knowing what `gem` is and how you originally set its `value` from the output of a `cPickle.dumps`...!

Answer (score 1):

The result of `cPickle.dumps()` is a `str` object, not a `unicode` object. You need to find the step in your code where you are decoding the pickled `str` object, and omit that step.

DON'T try to convert your `unicode` object to a `str` object. Two wrongs don't make a right. Example (Python 2.6):

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> ps = cPickle.dumps([1,2,3], -1)
>>> ps
'\x80\x02]q\x01(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.'
>>> ups = ps.decode('latin1')
>>> str(ups)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x80' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

You may well be using the default (and inefficient) Protocol 0 which produces "human readable" output:

```
>>> ps = cPickle.dumps([1,2,3])
>>> ps
'(lp1\nI1\naI2\naI3\na.'
>>>
```

which is presumably ASCII (but not documented to be so) so the `str(gem.value)` kludge may well """work""":

```
>>> ps == str(unicode(ps))
True
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it by making `gem.value` a string, not unicode.

Use `str(gem.value)`

Comment: -1 That's a kludge, not a fix. str() uses the default encoding. You would need to know how it was decoded in the first place.