# Convert argument to string

Tags: python, django, django-views

Never work with Struct before. When hire a developer for some work, he used this, but it doesn't work. And developer doesn't answer... Please, can someone help with the problem?

From `views.py`, that you can see below, I got error `Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode` in `'InvId': str(struct.unpack('=H', urandom(2))[0]),`. So, how to convert it to a string?

```
@login_required
def userprofile(request, username):

    extra_context = dict()

    if request.POST:
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        user_profile = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES,
                                       instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
        if user_profile.is_valid():
            user_profile.save()
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(
            instance=request.user,
            initial={
                'first_name': request.user.first_name,
                'last_name': request.user.last_name,
                'email': request.user.email,
            })
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        user_profile = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

    extra_context['user_form'] = user_form
    extra_context['user_profile'] = user_profile
    extra_context['robo_form'] = RobokassaForm(initial={
        'UserId': request.user.id,
        'OutSum': 1000,
        'InvId': struct.unpack('=H', urandom(2))[0],
        'Email': request.user.email,
    })

    return render_to_response('profile.html', extra_context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix this unicode/cPickle error in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946068/how-do-i-fix-this-unicode-cpickle-error-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct.unpack('=H', urandom(2))[0]` is just dumb. Just generate an integer in the readable way:

```
'InvId': random.randrange(2**16),
```